# How do I track a Paypal button click using Google Analytics event triggars

Tags: paypal, google-analytics

I'm trying to track in Google Analytics whenever a user clicks on a Paypal payment button. I have an event tracker set-up, but currently no event is being triggered when the button is clicked. Here is the paypal form with an onclick event trigger.

```
<form onclick="_trackEvent('buttonclick', 'buttonclick');"    action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ZDHHMPA9CQR54">
<input type="image" id="imageH" style="width:90%"  src="http://roadcams.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/buttons2.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the latest version of google analytics, you need a different function:

```
ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

so yours might be...

```
<form onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'paypal');" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ZDHHMPA9CQR54">
    <input type="image" id="imageH" style="width:90%" src="http://roadcams.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/buttons2.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```